# Which methods to use instead of if-else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a way to reduce the amount of code with lots of condition written in java netbean? I have used if-else statement with lots of conditions and realized my code is pretty lengthy. The conditions are taken from combo box and text field(haven't added yet).

I have a sample of the code at the bottom. I need to add 20+ of this so I am not sure if if-else statement is the only option.

```
    if (RegionBx.getSelectedItem().equals("Tokyo") &&
        SeasonBx.getSelectedItem().equals("Spring") && 
        MealBx.getSelectedItem().equals("Nil")) {
          TravelCost = Tokyo + (Tokyo * sphotel) + (Tokyo * spflight);
    }
```

Comment: With proper design sure, but there's no magic trick that you can use. In this case you could do something like keep the prices and price modifiers in `Map<String, Double>`s, so `price.get(city) * season.get(city)` etc.

Comment: Use a [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Because I am not an advance user of java so I don't really know other method other than if-else method.

Comment: @TontonVelu how would that help?

Comment: Here's one way: Find out what's different and what's the same among all the if statements. Write a method with the parts that are the same, with the parts that are different as parameters. And you call the method 20 times.

Comment: But switch method can only use integer? How about the other conditions which taken from other fields?

Comment: Switch method doesn't only work with integers, but it also won't help you here.

Comment: Sure, use a dictionary to map the text in the boxes to the costs then your code becomes one line where you add up all the costs of everything indexing the region/season/meal dictionaries by what the user chose

Comment: Best practice is to use the if else statement. Because there is no magic. if else is one of the core conditional statement of Java. Even if there will be some method, that method will also use if else statment.

Comment: Well all the conditions are derived from combo box field and text field so ...

Comment: @Kostakiiis From the combobox they are mostly have a few choices and from the text field they will need key in the number they need.

Comment: @user2963724 It is very good for you as for a beginner to ask such a question. I posted an answer, it may look complicated at first, but in practice it is very convenient, and I assume that you will often use similar approaches for tasks like that. My answer provides an example of the approach proposed by Caius Jard and Kayaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such pattern, that can reduce the number of `if-else` statements for every kind of architecture.

For your kind of task you should simply map strings to prices.

Get rid of the need to use conditionals. Use collections to keep possible output data associated with possible input data.

```
 Map<String, Integer> cityPrices = HashMap<String, Integer>();
 Map<String, Integer> seasonPrices = HashMap<String, Integer>();
 Map<String, Integer> mealPrices = HashMap<String, Integer>();

 // Don't forget to initialize your collections. 
 // Put possible string values and their prices in maps.

 cityPrices.put("Tokyo", 10000);
 ...

 Integer regionPrice = cityPrices.get(RegionBx.getSelectedItem()); 
 Integer seasonPrice = regionPrice * seasonPrices.get(SeasonBx.getSelectedItem());
 Integer mealPrice = regionPrice * mealPrices.get(MealBx.getSelectedItem());

 Integer travelCost = regionPrice + seasonPrice + mealPrice; // Now it is one line for all cases.
```

Comment: @user2963724 you are welcome. You can accept Stephen's or mine answer to make the question closed :)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without seeing the whole problem you are trying to solve.  But if the pattern of these tests is very uniform, there are various approaches that you could try.   For example

```
switch (regionBx.getSelectedItem() + ":" +
        seasonBx.getSelectedItem() + ":" +
        mealBx.getSelectedItem()) {
case "Tokyo:Spring:Nul":
    travelCost = tokyo + (tokyo * sphotel) + (tokyo * spflight);
    break;
...
}
```

Or:

```
String[][] criteria = new String[][]{
    {"Tokyo", "Spring", "Nul"},
    ...
};
IntSupplier[] computations = new IntSupplier[] {
    () -> tokyo + (tokyo * sphotel) + (tokyo * spflight),
    ...
};

String region = regionBx.getSelectedItem();
String season = seasonBx.getSelectedItem();
String meal = mealBx.getSelectedItem();
for (int i = 0; i < criteria.length; i++) {
    if (region.equals(criteria[i][0]) &&
        season.equals(criteria[i][1]) &&
        meal.equals(criteria[i][2])) {
        travelCost = computations[i]();
        break;
    }
}
```

(I am not sure I have the syntax of the 2nd version exactly right.  Please comment or edit.)

If you can express the calculation as a formula based on a limited set of factors that can be looked up in maps, see @Steyrix's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892219/139985).

---

However, it is not clear that the result will be better (more readable / more maintainable) than the version with lots of `if` tests.

And they are unlikely be more efficient.

My personal recommendation would be to use `if` tests in the first version and only spend effort on "polishing" the code if the method stretches to hundreds of lines of code.